# Custom expanded notification implementation on wear os

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, wear-os

## What I need

I need a wear notification that shows some summary text (which is formatted - so a custom layout here is needed), and when expanded a list of formatted text (another seperate custom layout) will show with actions at the bottom of the screen. I don't want to use any deprecated methods and it should be decorated similarly styling to android.

## What I've tried:

#### Remoteviews and decoratedCustomViewStyle

- This lead to no results, not showing the layout or text that i specified (I later found that this is stated by android too"

  > Notifications using RemoteViews
  >   are stripped of custom layouts and the wearable only displays the text and icons. However, you can create custom notifications that use custom card layouts by creating a wearable app that runs on the watch.
  >   [Found here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating)

#### setDisplayIntent

- This follows the [developer guidelines](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html#CustomNotifications) for custom notifications on wear. This looks fine and all but I found out it is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.WearableExtender#setDisplayIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)) in API level 29. A combination of setDisplayIntent and addPages would have been perfect.

#### setContentIntent

- This allows for a seperate activity to be launched on expand, and this is the kind of functionality I want, however, this is launching the app, and not baked into the android notification itself.

I'm really running out of ideas here, and was wondering if anyone has any up to date ways of making custom notifications like this, as there doesn't seem to be any updated guides.